# How to upload csv file through form-data in python

Tags: python, rest

In python project structure, I'm having the following csv file

> Test |-API.py |-Test.csv

In same folder I'm having both py and csv file

In postman, I'm getting 200 status, [POSTMAN working request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyclM.png)  but when I try this in python I get the following error:

```
status - 400; 'errors': {'': ['Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary.']}}
```

This is the code I followed

```
import requests

url = "https://example.com/upload/fileUpload"
f1 = open('Test.csv', 'rb')
data = {
    "AID": "5656gshg-77sj-4a8d-8ef8-b17ed5cad234",
    "BNO": "1",
    "CNO": "2",
    "ContainerName": "fileupload",
}
resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, data=data, files={'file': f1}, )
print(resp)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: It can be you are overwriting the postman settings and you get a conflict. Try removing the `headers` param. `resp = requests.post(url, data=data, files={'file': f1})`

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

It can be you are overwriting the Postman's settings and you get a conflict. Try removing the `headers` param. `resp = requests.post(url, data=data, files={'file': f1})`